# Swift Protocol declare multiple properties on same line

Tags: swift, syntax, swift-protocols

I have a Protocol with many properties that share the same type and accessors. I'd like to declare them all on the same line, as I would with a Struct, to save many lines of vertical code space.

Is there any Swift syntax to declare a Protocol with multiple properties of the same type on a single line, or in some kind of compressed format?

```
struct SomeStruct {
    var structA, structB: Int // ok
}

protocol SomeProtocol {
    var protoA: Int         { get } // ok
    var protoB, protoC: Int { get } // error
    var protoD, protoE: Int         // error
    
    // ok, but too verbose
    var protoF: Int { get }; var protoG: Int { get }
}
```

Attempting to declare multiple variables on the same line results in two errors:

> 'var' declarations with multiple variables cannot have explicit getters/setters
>
> Variable with implied type cannot have implied getter/setter

If I omit the getters/setters, the property is no longer valid for the Protocol:

> Property in protocol must have explicit { get } or { get set } specifier

Is there any way to apply the same `{ get }` to multiple protocol properties?

Comment: I'd offer a word of caution. Protocols with too many requirements are a code smell, because they're hard to conform to. It's an indication that the protocol might be doing too much, and as a result they restrict conformers. As an example, look at how the collection protocol hierarchy is broken down. If we only had one collection protocol did did everything `RangeReplaceableCollection` does, `Dictionary` would be impossible to conform, without artificially implementing the requirements by making them call `fatalError()`

Answer (score 1):

No, you can not.  See "Protocol Property Declaration" here:

https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Declarations.html#grammar_variable-declaration